# Getting URL GET parameter with Code snippets and storing it in database?

Tags: plugins, php, database

I need to extract specific parameter `utm_medium` that is passed as parameter to all pages or posts on my WP site and store it in database. So every time someone visits my post I must collect that parameter and store it in some table in database. First code works but only first time I visit that particular page, it stores parameter in table. Every other time I visit same page(post) with other value of that parameter it is not been saved. This is a code:

```
if(isset($_GET['utm_medium'])){
        global $wpdb;
        $tablename = $wpdb->prefix.'test';
        $wpdb->insert($tablename, array(
                                    'utm_medium' =>$_GET['utm_medium'],
            ));
}
```

It needs to be Auto Insert not Shortcode, and the code must be run everywhere. I am using WPCode to make PHP snippet with these config of snippets.

[image]

I've also tried this but with no success:

```
add_action('init','add_get_val');
     function add_get_val() { 
         global $wp; 
         $wp->add_query_var('utm_medium'); 
     }
    
     if(get_query_var('utm_medium')){
            global $wpdb;
            $tablename = $wpdb->prefix.'test';
            try{
                $wpdb->insert($tablename, array(
                                        'utm_medium' =>get_query_var('utm_medium')
                ));
            }catch (Exception $e){
            }
     }
```

Can I use this approach with WPCode PHP snippet and first code to make it store value every time?

Comment: query vars are not the same as GET variables, they're for whitelisting the parameters pass to `WP_Query`. If you want to fetch a URL parameter you should not be using `get_query_var`, you should be doing it the same way any other PHP code would, e.g. `$_GET` or `filter_input`. Aside from that, I read your question several times and did not understand, can you edit it to make it more understable/clearer?

Comment: There is nothing in the first code block which would be responsible for seeing it only execute on the first load of a particular page - the snippet plugin may well be responsible for that behavior; you might try implementing this functionality as a standalone plugin, perhaps using an `init` or `parse_request` hook. Regarding "Can I use this approach with WPCode PHP snippet" - questions regarding third-party extensions are off-topic here - you would need to enquire in the plugin's support channels for any questions regarding the abilities of that particular plugin.